# Knockout.JS - losing context?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In the following Fiddle I would like to be able to set the selectedFruit when clicking on one of the fruits in the list however this does not appear to be working.

After clicking on a fruit, if I inspect the value of viewModel.selectedFruit in a Chrome immediate window it appears to set the value to the viewModel object rather than the bound data item. What am I doing wrong? It appears that there is a loss of context somewhere?

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/paulsidebottom/LXssJ/8/)

Thanks

**Conclusion**

Whilst this helped track down the problem I was experiencing in my main app, the underlying problem was that in haste I had forgotten to use the KO template foreach binding on my `<UL>` and was using the templ foreach instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `viewModel` variable does not have global scope, as the fiddle's options are set to `onLoad` for how the JavaScript is loaded.  If you switch it to `no wrap (body)`, then you will be in good shape.

The only other change is that you can just use `$data` directly, rather than `$data()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LXssJ/10/

Comment: Many thanks - I knew it would be something trivial. Thanks for your efforts on KnockMeOut too - I'm a regular visitor.